# What to use as a unique ID for an order/transaction?

Tags: paypal, transactions, paypal-ipn

I'm setting up a PayPal checkout and I'm very confused with regard to the concept of the transaction IDs. I realize, for the same order, the merchant has a completely different transaction ID than the buyer, so using this transaction ID within a database table seems rather pointless, as it's not the ID the customer would provide in the case of an issue. What in the world am I supposed to use that is both available to myself and the buyer? I see there is an option for passing an invoice ID but according to PayPal's documentation, this is never presented to the customer anyway. Can somebody shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized the Invoice ID is indeed accessible to the buyer through their confirmation email and transaction details page. [PayPal's documentation](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside) of the invoice variable states "Optional pass-through variable that **will never be presented to your customer**. Can be used to track invoice numbers", which appears to be just flat out inaccurate.